# Approaching algorithms with modulo usage

Tags: algorithm, modulo

I was doing some coding challenges and a problem came up that said roughly this:

> "Two players each taking turns starting with player one. There are N
>   sticks given, each player takes 1, 2 or 3 sticks on their turn, the
>   player to take the last stick loses, the goal is to find an algorithm
>   that lets player one win with certainty (not always possible, player two is supposed to take turns that will ensure victory) and output 1, 2 or 3 as
>   the starting amount of sticks taken or 0 if it's impossible to win.
>   Input is N. Example: Input:2 Output:1"

I tried to think about it but all I came up with is that it would take checking every possible outcome because of all the possibilities that could be chained together if N is big. I also thought that if the last stick is to be taken by player 2 so as to not lose, that is N-1 is taken by player 1 (whether by taking N-1 only or N-1, N-2 or N-1, N-2, N-3) leaving N to player 2, that is the only way to ensure victory.
It turned out that the solution was (N-1) mod 4, but I can't understand why that is the case.

So my question is how do you approach a problem like that and why is the solution a modulo? Also is there a way to spot modulo problems like these? Other coders did it fairly quickly so I suppose practice makes perfect, but I have no idea where to start from.

Comment: @Eric's idea is good. Programming wise, using recursive is recommended for this kinda problem

Comment: Why not just the modulo formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is modulo 4 because if one player has the advantage, he can keep the same advantage by taking 3 sticks if the first player took 1, 2 if the first player took 2, and 1 stick if the first player took 3. The other player simply doesn't have any control anymore.

Take the problem backwards :

You don't have to care about a big N, you just need to analyze what the situation looks like when only 4 sticks or less are left.

Who will win when there are 1, 2, 3 or 4 sticks left?

Who will win when there are 4n+1, 4n+2, 4n+3 or 4n+4 sticks left?

Comment: What do you mean by advantage? And since the first player makes the first turn wouldn't then the second player always keep the advantage?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand it, I'll try doing a few more examples. So in the end it's repeated, just what modulo does, I see, thanks.